# HashMap.containsKey(key) failing to find key, with custom class used as key type

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, equals

TL;DR: I made a hashmap object with my own "Pair" class objects to be used as Keys. When I use hashmap.containsKey(Pair), it fails to find the key.

I have a class called Pair, code shown below. It's supposed to be a container for two objects. The first object can be of any type, whereas the second object must be an integer. This isn't great design but I coded it this way so I could reuse the class for other purposes within my program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pair<L> {
    private L left;
    private int right;

    public Pair(L left, int right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public L getLeft() { return left; }
    public int getRight() { return right; }

    public void ToString() {
        System.out.println(left + "," + right);
    }

    public boolean equals(Pair p) {
        return (this.getLeft().equals(p.getLeft()) && this.getRight() == p.getRight());
    }

    public ArrayList<Pair> neighbors(int rowLimit, int ColumnLimit) {
        ArrayList<Pair> neighbors = new ArrayList<Pair>();
        Pair neighborL;
        Pair neighborR;
        Pair neighborU;
        Pair neighborD;
        if (((int)this.left-1 >= 0)) {
            neighborU = new Pair((int)this.left-1, this.right);
//          neighborU.ToString();
            neighbors.add(neighborU);
        }
        if ((int)this.left+1 < rowLimit) {
            neighborD = new Pair((int)this.left+1, this.right);
//          neighborD.ToString();
            neighbors.add(neighborD);
        }
        if ((int)this.right-1 >= 0) {
            neighborL = new Pair((int)this.left, this.right-1);
//          neighborL.ToString();
            neighbors.add(neighborL);
        }
        if ((int)this.right+1 < ColumnLimit) {
            neighborR = new Pair((int)this.left, this.right+1);
//          neighborR.ToString();
            neighbors.add(neighborR);
        }
        return neighbors;
    }
}
```

I'm storing Pairs as keys in a hashmap like this:

```
Map<Pair, Integer> costSoFar = new HashMap<Pair, Integer>();
costSoFar.put(sLocale, 0);
```

When I run the line below, which is to say, if the key is not in the hashmap:

```
if (!costSoFar.containsKey(next))
```

It evaluates to true, even when I know the key is in there, as I've checked through debugging.
[image: The Key is Pair(4,1)]
[image: And the Key I'm looking for is Pair(4,1)]

If anyone can help clear up why the hashmap isn't recognizing the keys it'd be much appreciated. Perhaps my equals method isn't up to scratch?

Comment: Have you implemented hashCode?

Comment: Have you implemented `equals()`?

Comment: Also you may need to align your equals method with that of the default Object equals method (Object o) parameter vs (Pair p), see http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html

Comment: For the record, you haven't implemented `toString()` either. You should make it a habit to always use the `@Override` annotation when overriding a method.

Comment: You have not overridden `equals`, `hashCode`, nor `toString`. Using `@Override` and _following the Java naming conventions_ will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using Generics if L seems to be int too?

Replace your equals:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Pair){
         Pair p = (Pair)o;
         return (this.getLeft().equals(p.getLeft()) && this.getRight() == p.getRight());
    }
    return false;
}
```

And implement int hashCode():

```
public int hashCode() {
    return this.getLeft() * 31 + this.getRight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `containsKey(Object)` in `java.util.HashMap` use the `java.util.HashMap.getEntry(Object)` which call `hashCode()` to obtain the hashCode for the Key and use it to retrive the object. You need to override `java.lang.Object.hashCode()` to make your code properly work.